# Automatically setup a JENKINS 2.32.1 server (with a script)

Tags: jenkins

I am recently trying to automatically setup a jenkins server with a script.
The aim is, that I simply run that one shell scirpt after a fresh server (aws instance) is started and then the whole server is ready to use.

What does this mean:

- I don't wanna see that first question for the secret file (has to be done automatically or disabled)
- I don't want to set a admin password, well not by using the UI but by setting it via terminal.
- Add some users with permissions
- Add SSH private keys for connections to github/bitbucket
- Install pre-chosen plugins
- Additionally paste some existing jobs into that jenkins

Is there a way to do that? Or (what I didn't try so far) is it possible to just copy a pre-configured jenkins and run that? Like a "jenkins"-image =)

Answer (score 2):

The Jenkins home directory contains a `init.groovy.d` directory. 
Any groovy script within this directory is executed at boot in lexicographical order. Currently I am running my Jenkins master inside a container, which is pre-provisioned, but you could also easily use configuration management tools to provision your Jenkins master instance with these groovy scripts.

Here is one example I use for integrating private keys from `$JENKINS_HOME/.ssh` into my Jenkins credential store:

```
import jenkins.model.*
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.*
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.common.*
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.domains.*
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.*
import com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.*

domain = Domain.global()
store = Jenkins.instance.getExtensionList('com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.SystemCredentialsProvider')[0].getStore()

// private git keys
privateRepoKeys = ["key1", "key2"]

privateRepoKeys.each {
    privateKey = new BasicSSHUserPrivateKey(
        CredentialsScope.GLOBAL,
        "jenkins-${it}",
        "jenkins",
        new BasicSSHUserPrivateKey.FileOnMasterPrivateKeySource("/var/jenkins_home/.ssh/${it}"),
        "", 
        "Jenkins ${it} Key"
    )   

    store.addCredentials(domain, privateKey)
}
```

Here is another example that I use for adding a default admin:

```
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.security.*

def instance = Jenkins.getInstance()

def hudsonRealm = new HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm(false)
hudsonRealm.createAccount("my_admin", "my_pw")
instance.setSecurityRealm(hudsonRealm)

def strategy = new GlobalMatrixAuthorizationStrategy()
strategy.add(Jenkins.ADMINISTER, "my_admin")
instance.setAuthorizationStrategy(strategy)

instance.save()
```

I use more scripts to completely bootstrap my Jenkins (hooking it up with the slave machines, configuring global tools, configuring global variables...). So far I didn't hit a limitation with this for my use cases.

**Update:**

I just created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/fishi0x01/7c2d29afbaa0f16126eb4d4b35942f76) with a collection of groovy scripts I gathered and that I use to bootstrap Jenkins. Will try to keep it up to date.

Comment: That's very interesting. I will have to have a really close look at the groovy script. The only problem is: There is no `init.groovy.d` file in the home directory. There is just an empty folder structure `$JENKINS_HOME/.groovy/grapes`

Comment: @Timo I think it is not necessarily there by default, but you can create it and Jenkins will use it then. See [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=70877249). Only problem is that it is hard to find good documentation on how to use all the Jenkins plugins programmatically with groovy. I think in the following days I will create a gist with a collection of the groovy scripts I gathered from all over the web (was on my personal TODO list since a while...) - I will share the link in this answer then, maybe it will help as a starting point :)

Comment: Uh yeah! That would be really awesome! Thanks a lot for that!

Comment: @Timo I just added the gist to the answer - hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are many ways and steps to do that. You can have a look at the [Docker container](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/3cf0212a1a795902cabbd67b2920f4bedeb762fc/Dockerfile), [Chef cookbook](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/jenkins) or [Puppet module](https://forge.puppet.com/rtyler/jenkins). They do things like adding

```
-Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false
```

to Jenkins startup parameters.

They (at least Docker and Chef) also have their means to install plugins.

Answering this within a single question here is IMHO a bit too much, so I'm mainly pointing to off-site resources and ask you to post a new question, once your have a particular problem with one of the steps.

Comment: Great! That is actually very helpful! If I run into any particular issues, I'll ask again =)